# meager and residual subsets of real

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I know the definition of Meager and Co-meager subsets of $\\R$.  My question is 
Let  $A,B\subset{\\R}$ and$B$ is open  What is the definition of $A$ is meager in $B$ and Also $ A$ is co-meager in $B$. If there is a book that has a lot of details about meager and co-meager, the please let me know.

Comment: yes you are right but I did not get an answer this why I am asking again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A \subseteq B \subset {\mathbb R}$.  Then $A$ is nowhere dense in $B$ if the closure of $A$ relative to $B$ contains no interior points.  $A$ is meagre in $B$ if it's the union of sets that are nowhere dense in $B$.  $A$ is co-meagre in $B$ if the complement of $A$ is meagre in $B$.  So what you need to be certain you understand is what it means for a set to be closed relative to another.

As far as book recommendations go, Oxtoby's *Measure and Category* is practically the canonical reference for this kind of thing and gives some very nice explanations of how things can be meagre but have full measure and vice versa.

Comment: @poatmories Thank you, Do you mean in definition it requires to be a subsets always if so if this is standard definition

Comment: Closure is always relative to *some* enclosing set, whether that set is the whole space (i.e. $X$) or a subset of it.  I think it's easier to think of all the definitions as being defined in terms of subsets, and just remember that a lot of the time $B=X$.

Comment: Okay, let assume $A$ is a subsets of real number it makes sense to say meager without mentioning where

Comment: Yes, you can say that.  The assumption will be that $A$ is made up of sets nowhere dense in $\mathbb R$

Comment: How about residual subset of real number it is the same or not

Comment: Yes, residual subsets are complements of meagre sets, so exactly the same applies to them

Comment: This is help a lot also if another book in mind about these sets it would be helpful

Comment: Choquet's *Topology* covers everything you can think of, but it's a little old-fashioned so the notation can take some getting used to.  (Vol. I -- there are two volumes).  *Elementary Real Analysis* by Bruckner, Bruckner and Thomson also covers all this (I think) and is a bit more gentle

Comment: I found one volume for Choquet"s topology written by english since I can not read the France version